# How to create executable console app from .NET Core 2.0 in Linux?

Tags: .net, linux, .net-core

As far as I know in the https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/get-started/macos, we only able to run it:

```
$ dotnet run
```

I have a requirement to create a console app that we execute from a terminal as below:

```
$ ./my_console_app file_inputs.txt
```

How to create an executable that can run in a terminal like that?

Comment: I wonder why people are giving the question downvote, while I believe this is a pretty important question :(

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In order to create a standalone console app in Linux, you should use a self-contained deployment (SCD) publishing mode for your dotnet core app:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/index#self-contained-deployments-scd

This will generate a single binary that bundles the target framework and can be executed independently without any extra shell-scripts or pre-installed dotnet runtime.

I recommend to use the official dotnet cli `console` template and then publish your project as a `--self-contained` switch by specifying your [target runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog) (eg: `linux-x64`) and framework what you use.

So start with the basic `console` template:

```
dotnet new console -o myconsoleapp
cd myconsoleapp
```

Edit `program.cs` to process your input-file or other arguments based on your business logic, eg: `nano program.cs` and add something like:

```
using System;
namespace myconsoleapp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello Linux!");
            if (args.Length > 0) { Console.WriteLine("Input is: " + args[0]); }
        }
    }
}
```

Test your application with `dotnet run file_inputs.txt` and it should print to the console correctly.

In order to get the binaries and the bundled framework to be distributed, you should run `dotnet publish`:

```
dotnet publish -c release --self-contained --runtime linux-x64 --framework netcoreapp2.0
```

You can then distribute your `publish folder` and then execute your app just simply by:

```
./myconsoleapp file_inputs.txt
```

Here's a bit more detailed article about creating standalone Linux console app in dotnet core:

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/luisdem/2016/10/11/net-core-how-to-publish-a-self-contained-application-exe/

Also can read more here about other available Linux templates at the `publish` page:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish?tabs=netcore2x

Comment: Hi @muratiakos, so by doing that I can create an executable like what I want? it seems you're not answering my question.

Comment: Added now the `self-contained` description and article references to generate a single binary for execution without a shell script

Comment: Thanks, it could be a good alternative if we want to publish a standalone application. +1

Answer (score 3):

Finally, I'm able to find the answer and solve this by my self.
I created a shell script and made it executable.

```
$ touch my_console_app
$ chmod 777 my_console_app
```

I put this command to that newly created my_console_app file and saved it.

```
dotnet run --project ./path/to/your/project.csproj "$1"
```

Now I can run and execute my .net core project using this executable shell script and able to accept a parameter argument.

```
$ ./my_console_app file_inputs.txt
```

EDIT:

If you only have the .dll file from .net core project you can change the content of my_console_app into:

```
dotnet ./path/to/your/project.dll "$1"
```

Comment: when you have time, read about self contained deployment, and `dotnet publish --self-contained`. That would show you an even simpler approach.

Comment: Shell wrapper is also good approach, if you have dotnet runtime pre-installed already, but you can also check my answer regarding SCD publishing for single runtime bundled deployments: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49692221/4358231